# Can't locate background image

Tags: css

So I have a project I'm working on and Im trying to link URL's in the CSS files, All URL's are pointing towards files that are local and what ever way I type it its just not locating the files or Pictures

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mainbody';
    src: url('~/Content/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');

}

//footer
.footer {
    background-image: url("/backgrounds/footer.png");
    width: 1360px;
    height: 907px;
}
```

[image: File tree]

[image: css file]

They are the two ways I have tried , and neither of them work

Comment: where are these files in relation to the css file? A screenshot of your file/folder tree would help.

Comment: there you go , i have updated the main post

Comment: I can't see where your generated css file is. I generally have a css folder. In the root of this is my css file. All assets that are referenced in the css file alos go in here, so that they can be referenced like 'images/background.png' or 'fonts/awsome-font.woff'.

Comment: the CSS is just sat in the Content folder

Comment: the above should work then. remove the forward slash at the start of your image. `background-image: url("backgrounds/footer.png");`

Comment: URL's in CSS are relative to the CSS file they are defined in.  So if your en result CSS file that that the browser reads is at `/css` then any non-absolute url's will start in `/css` (regardless of where the page that links to it is).  If the url starts with / then it will be root relative, and must follow all the folders from the root of the site.  You cannot use the tilde (~) in css, as the browser has no idea what that means.  In ASP.NET the tilde means root of the site, but the browser doesn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mainbody';
    src: url('/Content/fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');

}

//footer
.footer {
    background-image: url("/Content/backgrounds/footer.png");
    width: 1360px;
    height: 907px;
}
```